# There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace : Magento 2

Tags: error, magento2, cli, code-generation

I have installed the `latest version of Magento 2`, everything is working fine frontend, backend and functionality.

I have one issue with  `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command, when I run this command in terminal I get below exception.

> [InvalidArgumentException]
> There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Is there anything I missed during installation or I need to install some package to let it work?

Comment: I think it is something wrong in your custom module config ..

Comment: Either way, it's pretty sad that something wrong with one module can bring down the core.

Comment: Please refer the below answer:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935850/there-are-no-commands-defined-in-the-setup-namespace-magento-2/34013490#34013490](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935850/there-are-no-commands-defined-in-the-setup-namespace-magento-2/34013490#34013490)

Comment: I face the same issue,  after digging the module.xml file there have a minor bug on sequence tag, once i fixed the issue everything is working fine.

Comment: When I see this message, I usually run `bin/magento` without any arguments, and it displays actual error

Answer (score 11):

In my case, it worked using sudo

`sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade`

**EDIT 19/02/16**

Actually, the "sudo" solution is more a workaround for bad permissions/ownership of Magento files.

If you don't already have a Magento file system owner, create one and add it to the apache group.

```
adduser magento
passwd magento
    //CentOS
    usermod -g apache magento

    //Ubuntu
    usermod -g www-data magento

//restart apache
    //CentOS
    service httpd restart

    //Ubuntu
    service apache2 restart
```

Now that you have your user, you can set the ownership and permissions (with root or an user with sudo)

```
cd /var/www/html/magento2beta/magento2
find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && sudo chmod +x bin/magento
//CentOS
chown -R magento:apache .
//Ubuntu
chown -R magento:www-data .
```

Switch to the magento user

```
su magento
```

Now you should be able to run php bin/magento setup:upgrade or any other command with your magento user

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: i am using windows. what i have to do for solving this?

Comment: You will also see this error when something is wrong with your custom module, for instance if the module.xml file **not** is placed in the etc directory and so on.

Comment: @MaYaNk, to solve this, use linux instead

Answer (score 9):

`There are no commands defined` is a generic message which hides a real problem.
I have opened the [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2300) stated that Magento 2 **should clarify** such messages, so please vote for it.
[In my cases](https://mage2.pro/t/176) the problem was with `composer.json` file and with an extension's `module.xml` file.
See also:

- All `There are no commands defined` [issues](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+There+are+no+commands+defined) in the tracker.
- All `There are no commands defined` [questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=There+are+no+commands+defined+%5B(inurl%3Amagento.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F+AND+intitle%3Amagento2)%5D) on `magento.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, did you get any solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: Of course, just read the links.

Comment: @Mage2.PRO please post the final solution here

Comment: There is no "the final solution" because it is individual. `There are no commands defined` just a generic message, it hides a real problem, and the real problem could be different.

Comment: @Mage2.PRO `There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace`. for this error what i have to do. i am using windows localhost

Answer (score 4):

This happens if any XML file defines in etc is not defined correctly. There could be a sequence problem or error in node defining

Open cmd go to your Magento root directory and type the below command.

```
D:\Server\htdocs\mage2>
D:\Server\htdocs\mage2>php bin/magento list
```

You will get relative error info.

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
  Invalid XML in file D:/Server/htdocs/mage2/app/code/Vendor/Module/et
  c/frontend/di.xml:
  Attribute sortOrder redefined
  Line: 4
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens if any XML file defines in etc is not defined correctly. There could be a sequence problem or error in node defining

Open cmd go to your Magento root directory and type the below command.

```
D:\Server\htdocs\mage2>
D:\Server\htdocs\mage2>php bin/magento list
```

You will get relative error info.

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
  Invalid XML in file D:/Server/htdocs/mage2/app/code/Vendor/Module/et
  c/frontend/di.xml:
  Attribute sortOrder redefined
  Line: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error and from other answers I am reading on here it is clearly caused by a variety of problems. But mine was caused because my dependency injection file at company/module/etc/di.xml was empty ! ( I had deleted the contents by mistake )

Magento was trying to load the file but it was empty so it was invalid and causing multiple errors including the one in this question

Just thought I would post this incase it saves some else 4 hours of their life !!

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the similar issue and in my case, the issue was due to missing `config.php` in `app/etc`.

Answer (score 0):

If you install magento in localhost, you should set permissions 777 for var and pub folder. This issue can resolved

Comment: Thanks for your reply, these folders already have 777 permission

Comment: And it not woking ?

Comment: yes not working

Comment: Any one got the solution to this? As I run this command then I got another issue/error i.e. pdo_mysql extension is not installed what to do can not figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I followed several suggested stupid suggestions to fix the problem like delete my composer.json something like that.
But those didn't fix my problem.
Today, I faced the problem again and I tried a new approach to trace the problem.
All details and screenshot are in my personal blog post
http://david.firstbiz.cc/blog_detail.php?id=115
I described my steps here:

```
1. for CLI, please append "-vvv" and it will display function trace paths
2. try to load any product page and check your web server error log and you will be able to see more details.
3. the class name and the filename should be same (*this is the case I faced)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be permission issue.
You can set

```
chmod -R 777 magento folder permissions.
```

Just for test and see if it will work. 
hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error just after you were trying to create a module, then make sure that you have added this files in your module. /etc/module.xml

Answer (score 0):

Please check the permission of your magentoDirectory.

> $sudo rm -rf var/cache/* generated/code/*
>
> $sudo chmod 777 -R magentoDirectory
>
> $sudo chown -R www-data:www-data magentoDirectory
>
> $php bin/magento setup:di:compile

$php bin/magento cache:clean

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue by restarting the server & and provide full permission to files and folder `chmod -R 777 .` in the local environment! :)

Answer (score 0):

To see exactly what the error message is, execute `php bin/magento list` and look at the error at the bottom.

---

This problem can also happen if your modules are disabled.
I changed to another git branch and suddenly all Magento Modules were disabled.

So I executed `php bin/magento module:enable --all` to fix it.

Remember to disable unneeded modules after it, for example `Magento_Csp` or `Magento_TwoFactorAuth` if you don't need them.

---

Another option is to manually delete the cache and try again.

```
rm -r var/cache/*
```

---

If this all does not work, then try to reset the permissions as last resort:

```
sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
sudo chown -R :www-data . # Ubuntu
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

↑ copy paste the whole block and execute it

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error can be seen in the command output: **`php -f bin/magento`**.

This will work for most errors like `There are no commands defined in the "..." namespace.`.

---

A fairly common cause is an error in `xml` files e.g. `VendorName/ModuleName/etc/config.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to restart mysql with **sudo systemctl restart mysql**.