# Magento 2 - There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace on windows

Tags: magento2, error, cli

I have a problem when I run this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Display error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>  There are no commands defined in the
> "setup" namespace.

I found some answers but not in my case(I run in Windows 7 and Xampp).
[There are no commands defined in the “setup” namespace : Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91673/there-are-no-commands-defined-in-the-setup-namespace-magento-2)

On frontend display:
[image]
Last time, I fixed is the system my pool code have errors with my module. And now I remove all my modules but error until display.
Anyone used to fix this problem, Can you tell me how to fix this problem?

When I run the command to install again composer, it returns error below:
[image]

Comment: check  extensions, maybe missing module.xml file

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Run this command:

```
php bin/magento list
```

When everything is working correctly, this should list out all of the possible commands in your Magento 2 command line interface. However, in the event that something is going wrong, this will also give you a much more descriptive error message about how and why it is failing.

This could be the result of an invalid composer.json module file, among other things.

See also: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/91696/1905

Comment: Thanks @Ryan. I tried many other answers, but yours helped me only.

Comment: Thanks, for me it thrown even error in list command but later i realized there is folder right problem

Comment: Great answer because it gives a more detailed error message. Was able to track down the issue after running this command.

Comment: thanks it was helpful it showed some error instead of nothingness

Comment: Thanks @Ryan above command helped us to identify the issue which went wrong

Comment: Can people share the particular issue they faced?

Answer (score 36):

Also happens when the module name in `module.xml` does not match with path based namespace. Please check your module name again: `code/Vendor/myModuleName/etc/module.xml`

We can read more here: https://gist.github.com/bka/d44fb33d1eaf780e1b76

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I followed several suggested stupid suggestions to fix the problem like delete my composer.json something like that.
But those didn't fix my problem.
Today, I faced the problem again and I tried a new approach to trace the problem.
All details and screenshot are in my personal blog post
http://david.firstbiz.cc/blog_detail.php?id=115
I described my steps here:

```
1. for CLI, please append "-vvv" and it will display function trace paths
2. try to load any product page and check your web server error log and you will be able to see more details.
3. the class name and the filename should be same (*this is the case I faced)
```

Comment: You blog is not reachable

Answer (score 0):

If anyone have dependencies (especially coming from custom modules) in you CLI class, you have to check all of the class for possible problems. If somewhere you are playing around with `RequestInterface` it can cause problem - but don't know why.