# Made a mistake in module.xml rectified it but not able to use the same module again

Tags: magento2.2

While creating a custom module if you gave the wrong module name, When you try to run any terminal command you will get an error like

> There are no commands defined in the “setup” namespace

Now I understand the solution from one of the answer in this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103774/magento-2-there-are-no-commands-defined-in-the-setup-namespace-on-windows).But when I try to change the module again, I am always end up in the same error even after I update everything Or I also tried removing other files. If I keep the registration.php it shows error If I delete the registration file, it works. How can I use the same module again.

Comment: you need to delete your module entry from setup_module table

Comment: But I can't found my module in the setup_module table.

Comment: just try with remove var folder and generated folder from root.

Comment: If you check your module namespace in file app\etc\config.php then available there?

Comment: No its not available there also.

Comment: I post answer, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove extension from the magento 2, you need to do following things.

1. Identify Magento 2 extension name, you can get name from `registration.php`.
2. Remove extension entry from `app/etc/config.php` (entry identify from step1)
3. Remove extension entry from `setup_module` table in magento database. (entry identify from step1)
4. After remove the things, please also run these commands.

   ```
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   php bin/magento cache:flush
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
   ```
5. Now added all your new file and run command again.

After this you can now used same module name for others.

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean by extension name here. FYI I am new to magento.

Comment: Extension name specify in registration.php file.

Comment: <?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
 'Foo_Bar',
 __DIR__
);




This is the file what is the extension name here.

Comment: here "Foo_Bar" is your extension name, You need to remove this entry from file and database table.

Comment: You mean Foo_Bar? I checked that in both setup_module table and config file it is not available.

Comment: Does your module avilable into list of extension?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71448/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-abel).