# How to fix "There are no commands define in the namespace" error?

Tags: composer, magento2.3.0, command-line

I have upgraded the Magento version from 2.2.6 to 2.3.0 via composer. I have tried running the command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` but it says the below error

> There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace

What could be the issue?

Please, anyone, help me

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103774/magento-2-there-are-no-commands-defined-in-the-setup-namespace-on-windows

Comment: I have two question 1) Are you using windows or linux? 2) Are working in local with xampp?

Comment: @Sanjay Gohil, Windows

Comment: @Siva, I am face same issue earlier, I have solved by setting php environment variable. First of all check your xampp php version whether it is compatible with Magento 2.3.0, and then set php environment variable.

Comment: I have checked and see that PHP version which we have is compatible with Magento 2.3.0