# no commands defined in the "setup" namespace. in Magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, error, setup-upgrade

I have problem when I run this command:

When running this commond after making custom modules.

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

I also try running the command.

> sudo chmod -R 777 var pub
>
> sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

But still gives same error.

[image]

Comment: share a screenshot of the command you are entering to get an idea of the location and exactly what you are trying.

Comment: Please update the error you're getting

Comment: I shared screnshot of my terminal.Hope you will getting exact bug.

Answer (score 2):

Run `php bin/magento list` command. It will listed all the **magento 2** commands interface if everything working correctly. If something is going wrong, this will also give you error message that why it is failing.

You can check with https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/91696/1905 also.

Comment: I already apply this step.which are mentioned from previous occurs query .

Comment: It may be due to folder permission of var and pub. Also check  `chown` permission.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

> php -f  bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: Same error occurs, not changes something .

Comment: Check module.xml file of your last installed extension. This error generally because of this file only

Answer (score 0):

Please check the path of command you entered.
Also please try this
    sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: path is correct,that is magento root directory.

Answer (score 0):

empty `var/generation` and `var/di`. clear the cache.
check folder permissions and then run `magento list`.
if that gives a list of commands you can run `setup:upgrade`.
otherwise it should give an error you can post here.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error for all commands in cli (not just setup) when I had a custom module that I was working on that didn't have a module.xml file. (More precisely, it did have one but I put it in the wrong place. :-/ )

If you're getting this while actively working on a module, check to see if your module's etc/module.xml is missing or unreadable or otherwise incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Check module.xml file of your last installed extension. This error generally occurs because of this file only.